# Bounds for $S=\sqrt{x(y+1)}+\sqrt{y(z+1)}+\sqrt{z(x+1)}$

Tags: inequality

Let $x,y,z\in[0,2]$ and $x+y+z=3$. What are the maximum and minimum of $$S=\sqrt{x(y+1)}+\sqrt{y(z+1)}+\sqrt{z(x+1)}?$$

When $x=y=z=1$, we have $S=3\sqrt{2}$.

For the upper bound, we can use the AM-GM inequality to get $$S\leq\frac{1}{2}(x+y+1+y+z+1+z+x+1)=\frac{9}{2},$$ but equality cannot hold since we need $x=y+1$, etc. simultaneously, which cannot happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little numerical investigation gives that the maximum is attained for $x=y=z=1$ and the minimum for $x=1,y=2$ and $z=0$. An intuitive proof of this fact can be achieved by noticing that $F(x,y,z) = \sum_{cyc} \sqrt{x(y+1)}$ is concave in every variable and thus, the minimum should be attained at extremal points and the maximum in the interior of the domain.

To prove rigorously the upper bound apply [Cauchy Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) to see that
$$ S^2 \leq (x+y+z)(y+1+z+1+x+1) = 18.$$
This implies that $S \leq 3\sqrt{2}$ and thus the maximum is $3\sqrt{2}$ and is attained only for $x=y=z=1$.

In order to find the minimal value we could suppose that $x \leq y \leq z$ and we look what happens if we replace the three values by $x-\varepsilon\leq y \leq z+\varepsilon$. We define
$$ f(\varepsilon)=\sqrt{(x-\varepsilon)(y+1)}+\sqrt{y(z+\varepsilon+1)}$$
and we note that
$$ f'(\varepsilon) = -\sqrt{\frac{y+1}{x-\varepsilon}}+\sqrt{\frac{y}{z+\varepsilon+1}} $$
Note that since $\frac{y+1}{x}>\frac{y}{z+1}$ (simple consequence of the ordering) for small $\varepsilon$ the derivative is negative. Thus $f(\varepsilon)<f(0)$. This means that increasing the distance between $x$ and $z$ decreases the value of the function.

We can choose $\varepsilon$ as large as the domain allows it until we reach an extremal case: $x=0$ or $z=2$.

**Case  1.** $x=0$. Then $y+z=3$ and we want to minimize $g(y,z) = \sqrt{y(z+1)}+\sqrt{z}$. This is a one dimensional problem. It is not hard to see that the same principle applies. If we enlarge the distance between $y$ and $z$ then the value of the function decreases. Thus the minimum is attained for $y=1,z=2$.

**Case 2.** $z=2$. The $x+y=1$ and we want to minimize $g(x,y) = \sqrt{x(y+1)}+\sqrt{3y}+\sqrt{2(x+1)}$. The same type of analysis applies and we get that the minimum is found for $x=0,y=1$.

Thus the minimal value is equal to $3$ and is attained for $x=0,y=1,z=2$.